# Puzzle + Function pointers

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I need to call a function "general_function()" when two params are set. Like:

.cpp file

```
if (var_a == 1) {
  general_function();
}

if (var_b == 1) {
  generam_function();
}
```

definition of general_function is:

```
function general_function() {
  // Some 40 lines
  // Some 20 lines .. *
  // Some 40 lines
}
```

Now, the situation is that in both calls, 20 lines which I marked with * are different. So, when var_a is set, a set of 20 lines will be executed and when var_b is set,  another set of 20 lines will be executed.

There are lots of ways to overcome this situations. Create functions, pass params etc. But I wanted to do something from OOP's world. And that is why I created function pointer there. So, this is what I have done:

.h file

```
bool function is_a_set(string str, char* name) {
  // Do something
}

bool function is_b_set(string str, char* name) {
  // Do something
}
```

.cpp file

```
if (var_a == 1) {
  general_function(is_a_set);
}

if (var_b == 1) {
  general_function(is_b_set);
}
```

definition of general_function is:

```
function general_function(bool (*choice)(string, char*)) {
  // Some 40 lines
  choice(string, char*);
  // Some 40 lines
}
```

I hope it is clear until now. But I do get "error: no matching function for call to general_function()'

Can you spot anything?

Comment: `function` is not a keyword in C++, is it?

Comment: "There are lots of ways to overcome this situations." ?? *What situation?* An `if` test ?? Are you asking how to conditionally execute code without actually testing the condition?

Comment: function isn't a keyword...  has OP type def'd or defined it as a class?

Comment: @CarlNorum: I don't think so.  What some languages call a `function`, I believe C and its descendants call `method that returns a value`.

Comment: Aside:  I think -4 is a little harsh.  WP:BITE.

Comment: also using a function pointer isn't really an OOP thing

Comment: function is not a keyword in C++,

Comment: ***A puzzle of function pointers*** :)

Comment: OP: are a_is_set and b_is_set mutually exclusive? for some scoping? for a global scoping?

Comment: Guys, chill. function is not a keyword in c++. I wrote it there for better clarification.

Comment: Better clarification would be showing us the actual code.  Adding incorrect syntax for 'better clarification' seems like a stretch.

Comment: Whoz craig: Situation to manage code across two calls.

Comment: I did not knew though people care so much about syntax and all. I thought that giving clear picture would be enough. :)

Comment: Now this is at -5?  I concur:  **Guys, chill.**

Comment: Ok. So for "clarity", You have a function that can take conditional code paths based on elements within that function. You desire to provide a "general" solution to evaluating the conditionals in that function by giving it a function pointer to which it will pass its data, and thereby determine which code path to take based on the result. (akin to comparator functors for standard library container sorting, as an example). Consequently you can change the behavior of the function by changing the function pointer you give it. Is *that* accurate??

Comment: WhozCraig, yes that is correct.

Comment: OK then. At least we're in the same ballpark now.

Comment: WhozCraig and Codes with Hammers.
I want to know what did I messes up in the post to get -5.. :)

Comment: You would need enough **reputation** to gain the privilege to see who voted.

Comment: @HemantBhargava Likely the lack of clarity in the question and incoherent code were partly at play. Regardless, we stuck with it to try and understand what you were doing. There are a few answers that might bring you some good info.

Comment: Function pointers are **far** from OOP, and it is unclear why anything like this could be better than a simple `if` at the right place. You should clarify why an `if` does solve the issue, or what do you thing the function pointer will help with. Making it OO... that is not a reason to use function pointers (it is more of a reason **not** to use function pointers!) Not to mention that there are no objects in the description of the problem at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as to avoid the complexities of function pointers and tackle this in a more OOP kind of way, consider using inheritance and virtual functions.

```
class BaseThing
{
public:
    bool generalFunction( )
    {
        // some 40 lines of code

        specialMethod( );

        // some other 40 lines of code
    }

    virtual void specialMethod( ) = 0;
};

class AThing : public BaseThing
{
public:
    virtual void specialMethod( )
    {
        // special code for A
    }
};

class BThing : public BaseThing
{
public:
    virtual void specialMethod( )
    {
        // special code for B
    }
};
```

Then just use the object you need for a given situation:

```
BaseThing* thing = new AThing( );

thing->generalFunction( );

delete thing;

thing = new BThing( );

thing->generalFunction( );
```

Comment: I'm not convinced `general_function()` is even a member of a class, based on the OP's posting at least.

Comment: I know, I made some assumptions. But he said he wanted something more OO and I figured 'let me just show him some code that addresses a potentially similar issue'. I agree, though.

Comment: Well done.  That is what virtual functions and polymorphism are for.

Answer (score 0):

**function** is not a keyword in C++, Also function pointer declaration is wrong, it should be

```
void general_function(bool (*choice)(string, char*)) {
   /**/
}
```

Comment: Ha ha. :) What is the difference your function pointer and my function pointer syntax.. ?

Comment: It was for your earlier question, you updated while i was commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I might do; please understand that I haven't worked with headers or with function pointers in a while.

In the class:

```
private int var_a;
private int var_b;
```

And in the general method:

```
void general_function()
{
    //40 lines that run no matter which variable is set
    if ( var_a == 1 )
    {
        //20 lines that run if var_a is set
        //or better yet, call a submethod
    }
    //if var_a and var_b are mutually exclusive, use else if
    if ( var_b == 1 )
    {
        //20 lines that run if var_b is set
        //or better yet, call a submethod
    }
    //40 more lines that run no matter which variable is set
}
```